# Frozen at startup screen Ubuntu 17.10 new install

Tags: boot

I am windows user and needed to switch to ubuntu for my research. I downloaded 64 bit Ubuntu 17.10 iso and made a an UEFI bootable USB for install.

Then I made some changes from legacy support to UEFI based boot selection.

Everything happened smoothly and I successfully installed a UEFI bootable Ubuntu which smoothly launches until user ID prompt. After I enter the password I am left with a frozen screen as attached. Then all I had is to hold power button to turn off.

I have tried all the possible help from google but this doesn't go away?

Lenovo B40-30 (Intel Pentium) 4th generation, 4gb Ram, 500gb Harddrive.